# installing application prerequisites

Tags: command-line

I am a newbie to Linux environment. I am trying to install snort on my Ubuntu machine, while I am installing it, it often gets stuck in middle and says:  `libnet, zlib, daq are not found`. So I tried to download these packages. Then I started installing snort again and this time is saying that `pcre is not found`. In windows if I install some software it will ask these package are needed to install and it will download that to perform the installation. Likewise is there any commands or something else to know what files are needed before the installation starts.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to specify how you are trying to install it, i.e. using which commands or applications.

Comment: What was wrong with `sudo apt install snort` (since snort is [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=snort))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Snort** is a signature based intrusion detection system, it either drops or accepts the packets coming on a certain interface depending on the rules you have used. Follow the below steps to install it properly:

**Section - I: Preparing your System**

Before actually installing Snort, run these commands to install all the required pre-requisites:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

- Reboot your system after running the above commands
- Open the command-line interface again and run these commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install build-essential
  sudo apt-get install -y libpcap-dev libpcre3-dev libdumbnet-dev
  sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev openssl libssl-dev
  sudo apt-get bison flex
  ```
- Now your system is ready to install Snort

**Section - II: Installing Daq**

Snort requires "Daq" to run. You can create a separate folder for all your downloads  `mkdir ~/snort`.  It will keep all your downloads in one place. Download and Extract "Daq" using the commands:

```
cd ~/snort
wget https://www.snort.org/downloads/snort/daq-2.0.6.tar.gz
tar -xvzf daq-2.0.6.tar.gz
cd daq-2.0.6
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

- Above commands will download the "daq" source code and then install it properly.

**Section - III: Installing Snort**

You are now ready to download the Snort source code. Run the following commands:

```
cd ~/snort
wget https://www.snort.org/downloads/snort/snort-2.9.8.3.tar.gz
tar -xvzf snort-2.9.8.3.tar.gz
cd snort-2.9.8.3
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/snort /usr/sbin/snort
```

Snort is now installed on your system, but you will still have to configure it properly to use it. Run the `snort -V` command to ensure Snort is properly installed on your system.

**Section - IV: Creating some required Directories**

"Snort" need some folder and files to place its logs, errors and rules files. If you are good with bash script, create it, or else run these commands at once or you can just execute them one by one:

```
sudo groupadd snort
sudo useradd snort -r -s /sbin/nologin -c SNORT_IDS -g snort

sudo mkdir /etc/snort
sudo mkdir /etc/snort/rules
sudo mkdir /etc/snort/rules/iplists
sudo mkdir /etc/snort/preproc_rules
sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules
sudo mkdir /etc/snort/so_rules


sudo touch /etc/snort/rules/iplists/black_list.rules
sudo touch /etc/snort/rules/iplists/white_list.rules
sudo touch /etc/snort/rules/local.rules
sudo touch /etc/snort/sid-msg.map

sudo mkdir /var/log/snort
sudo mkdir /var/log/snort/archived_logs


sudo chmod -R 5775 /etc/snort
sudo chmod -R 5775 /var/log/snort
sudo chmod -R 5775 /var/log/snort/archived_logs
sudo chmod -R 5775 /etc/snort/so_rules
sudo chmod -R 5775 /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules


sudo chown -R snort:snort /etc/snort 
sudo chown -R snort:snort /var/log/snort 
sudo chown -R snort:snort /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules

cd ~/snort/snort-2.9.8.3/etc/ 
sudo cp *.conf* /etc/snort 
sudo cp *.map /etc/snort 
sudo cp *.dtd /etc/snort 
cd ~/snort/snort-2.9.8.3/src/dynamic-preprocessors/build/usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor/ 
sudo cp * /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicpreprocessor/
```

**CAUTION:** Please do not ignore these commands.

**Section - VI: Editing Snort configuration files**

We also need to modify some configuration files to run Snort in network intrusion detection mode. For this, we would need to comment out all the rules in snort configuration file. Here's the command:

```
sudo sed -i "s/include \$RULE\_PATH/#include \$RULE\_PATH/" /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

Once you have commented out all the rules, it is time to test Run the Snort.

**Section - VII: Testing Snort**

To make sure that Snort is running in network intrusion detection mode, we need to insert a rule in our Rules file. So, open it and run the following rule:

```
alert ip any any -&gt; any any (msg:"ATTACK RESPONSES id check returned root"; content: "uid=0(root)"; classtype:bad-unknown;
```

sid:498; rev:3;)

- Now run Snort using: `sudo snort -A console -q -u snort -g snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -i ens3`

**Note:** It will start listening on **interface ens3**, so, make sure you replace it with your interface name. After running Snort, open another **SSH Connection** to the server and run this command: `ping -b 255.255.255.255 -p "7569643d3028726f6f74290a" -c3`

You should now be able to see alerts on SSH where you have started Snort.

Comment: Please use [block code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) when posting multiple commands, I’ve edited it this time. Also note that you can specify multiple files for all of the commands `mkdir`, `touch`, `chmod`, `chown`, `cp`, it’s not necessary to duplicate these lines.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I couldn't edit my response due to power failure. Will ensure it isn't repeated.